# Given a string / filename produce a hash in R?

Tags: r, string, hash

I have a set of file names:

```
f <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

I have found `digest` function to do this, can you please advise if have chosen the right function for the task?

Comment: "if have chosen the right function for the task?" For what task? What is your expected output? What is the code you used that didn't work?

Comment: @avid_useR I have used digest, I am asking if this is the right function to use for hashing filenames?

Comment: So you're asking us to tell you if you chose the right function?  What does the documentation say?

Comment: What do you mean by "right function"? It either does what you want or it doesn't. If not even you can tell us what you're looking for, how can we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a `for` loop as well

```
for(i in f) print(digest(i, serialize = FALSE))
#[1] "0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"
#[1] "92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f"
#[1] "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33"
```

---

Or using `Vectorize`

```
Vectorize(function(x) digest(x, serialize = FALSE))(f)
#                                a                                  b 
"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661" "92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f" 
#                                 c 
#"4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maby sapply can work for you

```
library(digest)
f <- c("a", "b", "c")
sapply(f, digest, algo="md5", serialize=F)
```

The result is:

```
               a                                  b                                  c 
"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661" "92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f" "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33"
```